# Java EE, how to implement an update correctly?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm starting with my first Java EE project.
Now I read a bit the documentation and have a question about the performance or style of an update. What is better:

```
@Override
public void updateBook(BookTO to) {
    BookEJB book = new BookEJB(to.getISBN());
    book.setFinishedReading(to.getFinishedReading());
    book.setRating(to.getRating());
    entityManager.merge(book);
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void updateBook(BookTO to) {
    BookEJB book = entityManager.find(BookEJB.class, to.getISBN());
    book.setFinishedReading(to.getFinishedReading());
    book.setRating(to.getRating());
}
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`entityManager.merge()` is not simply an update action .It is an `update or insert` action as `merge()` will insert a record too if this book record does not exist in database.

The second way is the correct way to update the existing record in JPA . But pay attention that  you should check if the `book` object returned from  `entityManager.find()` is null or not before updating its properties. If this book record cannot be found in the database , null will be returned and you will have `NPE` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is the second solution, `merge` operation could lead to unattented changes when `BookEJB` will evolve (new fields added but initialized with other values than the ones in the database, etc...).

BTW, I imagine your method is in service layer, did you put transaction annotation to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the methods are invoked within a transaction. You can achieve a container-managed transaction:

1. Call the method within an EJB
2. Use newly introduced @Transactional on a POJO method

Or within a user transaction.

By default, optimistic locking is enabled if you are using:

```
@Version
private int version;
```

You can also enable pessimistic locking by explicitly locking the entity when reading it.